# How to disable/suppress the Security Alert for "security certificate is invalid" for Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-10, outlook-2016

I am not the network engineer that is in charge of this, but I get these popups often. I have read a few [articles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/276597/how-to-turn-off-e-mail-matching-for-certificates-in-outlook) about how to suppress the popups by updating the registry, but so far they haven't worked. I checked this [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/627870/outlook-security-alert-the-name-on-the-security-certificate-is-invalid-or-does) as well, but it is all things that I cannot do. I just want to suppress the messages.

When I click the "View Certificate" it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You should tell your Office administrator to get a proper certificate so that the security of the system is not compromised.

Comment: Also, it might be that the cert is valid (it isn't expired at least) but they haven't chained the certificate correctly.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I have told them that they need to fix this. Their response is that it "works fine for all other divisions in the company".

Comment: @varlogtim Not sure what you mean by "chained the certificate correctly"

Comment: So, `Network Solutions OV Server CA 2` - which is what that cert is signed by, appears to be an intermediate cert (https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/440ff68a35e03995ac55e457a67eb1680f9a7cdd.txt), that is issued by another intermediate cert (https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/USER-Trust-RSA-Certification-Authority.html) which finally points to a root CA. The point being, the issuer of the cert doesn't look like a root CA.

Comment: @varlogtim, that sounds like a problem, but I don't know anything about it. This is not my area of expertise. How can this be fixed or in my case just bypassed?

Comment: I think maybe the answer to your question might be that you can't bypass/disable this check. There are tons of examples of how to make sure you have the correct intermediate certs added to Exchange. Best of luck!